# Adding file to zip in gradle

Tags: gradle, zip

I'm currently building a zip in gradle from file referenced in a configuration using the following code:

```
task makeZip(type: Zip) {
baseName 'libsZip'
from configurations.compile
exclude { it.file in configurations.common.files }
```

Additionally I want to add an image file (logo.png), located in the same directory of the build.gradle .
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply add it with one more `from` method call like:

```
task makeZip(type: Zip) {
    baseName 'libsZip'
    from configurations.compile
    from ('logo.png')
    exclude { it.file in configurations.common.files }
}
```